# Factor $x^3 + 3x + 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Factor $a(x) = x^3 + 3x + 2$ as irreducible polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$

EDIT: Moved solution originally posted here as an answer to my own question.

Comment: That's right, all right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the polynomial is irreducible.

The factorization should have three polynomial of degree 1, or one polynomial of degree 2 and one of degree 1.

Note that if a factor of degree 1 exists, then I should be able to find a value $r \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ such that $$a(r) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ 5)$$

Since there's no such $r$ that annihilates the polynomial, no factorization of $a(x)$ can exist.